# Can i please get some lead on a Redshift sql to convert columns value from {NEWHP}{E_6123} to NEWHP_18_SN_123

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

Can we by any means using REGEX functions and or CASE /DECODE combination  of Redshift convert a string like  {NEWHP}{E_6123}  to  NEWHP_18_SN_123   here we need to take the string in first capture group as is then chuck out the alphabets in the second string , then  concat _ and then if the number next  is 5 then 16, if 6 then 18, and if 8 then  20 and concat SN and then _ followed by the last three digits .

Much thanks in advance . Please help if possible .

so as to summarize the rule be like : string inside first parentheses_number translated by above rule(is 5 then 16, if 6 then 18, and if 8 then  20 ) from first number in second parentheses_SN_last three numbers in second parentheses

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve it through split part function . Was first able.to split by } then clean the string with replace of { to null . Post that the second string was further split by _ and subsequent parts were captured by using substring to later concat as per desired requirement